# How does Gpay enable NFC from within the app?

Tags: android, kotlin, nfc

Not sure this is the correct place for this as it's a very open-ended question and I do not have a minimum reproducible result.

I'm trying to prevent having to launch an intent and have the user navigate to the "Settings" > "Connection" screen to enable NFC. I've read through the posts regarding enabling NFC programmatically, all of which say it is not possible.

For Gpay, if NFC is not enabled, the app gives you the option to enable it from directly within the app. Is this because Gpay/Google has access to tools that are not publicly available in the Android SDK? Or is there some way to enable NFC similar to what Gpay does?